# jquery slideIn/Out transitions wont work IE, or Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, transition, slide

okay im making it where when you goto the website it slides down the content(#wrap) and as it is sliding down make it where a loading graphic is displayed(.topnav img). then when you click a link in the nav(.topnav a) it slides the content up and again displays the loading graphic, but when the graphic is displayed this time it pauses for 500ms and then redirects.

this is not working in IE or Firefox, and im not really sure why it isnt. help me? also why doesnt IE8 support jquery's fadeIn/fadeOut method?

[jsbin link](http://jsbin.com/odugu4/3/edit)

The problem with IE and Firefox is when i click the links it doesnt do the exit animation and just goes straight to the link.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var wrap = '#wrap';

$(wrap).css(
    'display', 'none' // makes no content viewable
)
$(wrap).slideDown(1000, function() {
    $('.topnav img').fadeOut('fast'); // makes content slidedown and then the loading     image fadeout
});
$('.topnav a').click(function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    linkLocation = this.href;
    $(wrap).slideUp(1000, function() {
        $('.topnav img').fadeIn('fast', pause);
    });
});

function redirectPage() {
    window.location = linkLocation;
}
function pause() {
    setTimeout(redirectPage, 500);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this:

```
$('.topnav a').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    linkLocation = this.href;
    $(wrap).slideUp(1000, function() {
        $('.topnav img').fadeIn('fast', pause);
    });
});
```

`event` won't be defined in all browsers here, you instead want the event object that jQuery passed as the first argument to the [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) handler, like this:

```
$('.topnav a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    linkLocation = this.href;
    $(wrap).slideUp(1000, function() {
        $('.topnav img').fadeIn('fast', pause);
    });
});
```

[You can test the fixed version here](http://jsbin.com/odugu4/2/edit).

---

As an aside, since you're using `wrap` repeatedly, cache the jQuery object instead of the selector for less duplicate work, like this:

```
var wrap = $('#wrap');
```

...then just use `wrap` instead of `$(wrap)` in your code below.

Comment: okay thank you i will try it, whats the difference between e and event?

Comment: @user645607 - oh you can call the variable whatever you want, but since `event` is a global object in some browsers, I personally opt for just "`e`" instead...you could name it "`myEventVariable`" and use `myEventVariable.preventDefault();` just the same.

Comment: AH! okay thats fine. i have found out another problem. whenever im in Firefox and IE and click the links it doesnt do the exit animation it just skips it all and goes to the link

Comment: @user645607 - check the demo in the link above...make sure you're function looks like the code above, with `e` as the first argument , e.g. `$('.topnav a').click(function(e) {` and not still `$('.topnav a').click(function() {`

Comment: Thank you Thank you! that is what was wrong, now can you tell me what that does? im guessing it just calls the 'code'e'code' that prevents defaults in the function?

Comment: @user645607 - jQuery passes [the event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) for that click event as the first argument to your handler (that anonymous function), so you're just giving that argument a name and using it, so you can call the [`.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) on it, make sense?